# Will the use of a Bounded Buffer (Producer/Consumer) avoid the pain of having sync methods/deadlocks?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, buffer, deadlock

I'm coding a simple Bank simulator where users would login from different locations at once, using sockets. In the Bank server I keep a bounded buffer to store every incoming request, ex: transfer funds, get account balance etc and there's a Background Thread running at Server end (Buffer Reader) to pull out each request from this Request Queue (assume it works as a Thread Scheduler in OS), in FCFS basis.

I have made buffer's put() and get() methods to have conditional synchronization.

ex:

```
// put method
while(total_buffer_size == current_total_requests) {

 System.out.println("Buffer is full");
 wait();

}
```

So my question is, **do we have to synchronize methods** like get-balance or transfer-funds to avoid corruption of data? I believe it is not necessary since the Buffer Reader takes each request **one-by-one** and relevant action. **Have I avoided any deadlock situations** through this? What do you think? Thanks

EDIT2:

```
public synchronized boolean put(Messenger msg, Thread t, Socket s) throws InterruptedException {
        while(total_buffer_size  == current_total_requests) {

            System.out.println("Buffer is full");
            wait();

        }
        current_total_requests++;

        requests[cur_req_in] = new Request(msg, s); // insert into Queue

        cur_req_in = (cur_req_in + 1) % total_buffer_size ;

        notifyAll();

        return true;
    }

    // take each incoming message in queue. FIFO rule followed
    public synchronized Request get() throws InterruptedException {

            while(current_total_requests==0) wait();
            Request out = requests[cur_req_out];
            requests[cur_req_out] = null;

            cur_req_out = (cur_req_out + 1) % total_buffer_size ;
            current_total_requests--;
            notifyAll(); //wake all waiting threads to continue put()
            return out;

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to synchronize as you are only performing one action at a time. But this can severely hinder the overall performance because if you get a thousand requests, and it takes 4ms to handle each request, the last guy in the queue has to wait nearly 4 seconds to get a response from your server. Thats a long time!!

Comment: +1 for quick reply. This is for an academic project where performance is not much considered. I somehow need to prove that there won't be any deadlock situations. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one consumer (i.e. one thread that consumes the requests from the "buffer") , then you don't need to use any synchronization on the methods relating to the bank account. However, I don't believe that your current implementation of a "bounded buffer" is valid. To be more specific:

```
while(total_buffer_size == current_total_requests) {

 System.out.println("Buffer is full");
 wait();

}
```

There is absolutely no guarantee how many threads will get past the while loop, perform a context switch just before `current_total_requests` is incremented and queue more requests than what's allowed the buffer size. Unless your `put` method is synchronized, this approach will be extremely unreliable and prone to race conditions.

If you want a bounded buffer, then just use one of Java's already existing "bounded buffers" or more specifically: the [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html). The `BlockingQueue` blocks on `put(...)`:

> Inserts the specified element into this queue, waiting if necessary for space to become available.

It also blocks on `take()` if there is no data in the queue. I don't know if you can use one of the items in the concurrency library, but if you can't then you have to fix your `BoundedBuffer`.

Comment: [QUOTE] If there is only one consumer (i.e. one thread that consumes the requests from the "buffer") , then you don't need to use any synchronization on the methods relating to the bank account. [/QUOTE] Only one Buffer Reader thread will be pulling out requests from Buffer, execute relevant action and acknowledge each thread who has sent the request. It's a must to use my own Bounded Buffer.

Comment: @coder, kk, I just saw your edit and it looks fine since you synchronize the `put`/`get`. You can ignore my initial concern about the race condition. You should check the "corner" cases like what happens if the user makes a bounded buffer of size 0 and you try to `put`/`get`? What about size 1? (I haven't gone through your logic to see what would happen, but you may want to think about those)